# creating slider bar using pangolin

Tags: c++, opengl, pangolin

Is there any way to create slider using pangolin? small example of creating slider with min and max value, when user clicks on ok button then call a function.

Comment: Thanks for the edits :) i understood my question after the edits and answered my own question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some back Rand D i figured out a way to create a slider sort of thing: posting my answer incase if it can be of any ones help:

```
pangolin::Var<float> menubf("menu.bf:", 10, 100, 150 );
pangolin::Var<float> menuthDepth("menu.thDepth", 0, 0, 100 );
pangolin::Var<float> menudepthMapFactor("menu.depth Map Factor", 0, 0, 100 );
pangolin::Var<float> menufps("menu.fps", 0, 0, 100 );
```

First value initial value when u load the application, second value :once u move it as a slider the initial value will be changed second value, 3rd value: end value (final value: slider will move till last value)